# How can I make dialog created by Intent.createChooser() cancelable?

Tags: android

How can I make dialog created by `Intent.createChooser()` cancelable? In other words: when I'm tapping outside of **this** dialog I need it to be canceled.

By default it's working like this. But on some devices (like Samsung GT2) it's not (this dialog can be canceled only by pressing `back` button).

**NOTE** I'm talking about dialog created by `Intent.createChooser()`. I don't have reference to `Dialog` itself.

Comment: I think maybe they modified source. So the solution is create your own chooser using `Dialog` (so you can set outside cancelable) and `queryIntentActivities()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Yul -- this is not possible, except by creating your own chooser. `queryIntentActivities()` can give you the contents of the list, and you can design your dialog however you wish. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot) using `queryIntentActivities()` to populate a `ListView` of all `LAUNCHER` activities, then using that data to launch the clicked-upon entry.

Personally, since most devices will have this behavior already, I would not bother. I have been using Android since the original devices, and I had not realized that this dialog was cancelable by means *other* than the dialog's Cancel button (on older devices) and the BACK button until reading your question. I am skeptical that your user base will mind your app behaving the same as all other apps on their device in terms of chooser behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this with `startActivityForResult` then you can get the `resultCode` and test to see if it is `RESULT_CANCELED`.

There's more information about this in the [training documentation for Getting a Result from an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) and the [documentation for Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) itself.

While shamelessly borrowing examples from the above documentation, I'll show you how I'm doing it:

```
static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1;

private void pickContact() {
    Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
    pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
    startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ...
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        ...
    }
}
```